# PBR routing doesn't work on Ubuntu 22.04 Server

Tags: networking, 22.04, iptables, netplan, routing

I'm attempting to configure my server, but it's proving to be impossible. Thus, you are my last hope!

To provide some context, my virtual server (Ubuntu 22.04 server TLS) has 3 network devices connected to different networks:

- ens160 (Internet)
- ens192 (service)
- ens224 (management)

In my company, it is mandatory to separate the management service from the web service on my internal network. Therefore, I need to route the incoming traffic accordingly.

As far as I know, netplan cannot achieve this as it is based on static routing. That's why I'm trying to accomplish it with PBR (iptables), but I'm not succeeding!

Here are the steps I have taken:

1. iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i ens192 -j MARK --set-mark 1
2. iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i ens224 -j MARK --set-mark 2
3. Add tables in /etc/iproute2/rt_tables:

- 201 ens192_table
- 202 ens224_table

4. ip route add 10.10.0.0/16 dev ens192 table ens192_table
5. ip route add 10.10.0.0/16 dev ens224 table ens224_table
6. ip rule add fwmark 1 table ens192_table
7. ip rule add fwmark 2 table ens224_table
8. uncomment net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 in /etc/sysctl.conf
9. sudo sysctl -p
10. Netplan:

```
network:      
  version: 2      
  renderer: networkd      
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [172.16.0.4/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
        search: []
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 172.16.0.1
    ens192:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [172.16.1.4/24]
      routes:
        - to: 10.10.0.0/16
          via: 172.16.1.1
    ens224:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [172.16.2.4/16]
      routes:
        - to: 10.10.0.0/16
          via: 172.16.2.1
```

The local and perimeter firewalls are working perfectly.

Here's the issue I'm facing: When I ping from the IP 10.10.5.20 to the IP 172.16.1.4, the traffic goes back through ens192 (OK). However, when I ping from the IP 10.10.5.20 to the IP 172.16.2.4, the traffic also goes back through ens192 (Not OK). It should be going back through ens224.

Finally, my question is:

Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thank you for your assistance.